# Is there a good replacement for RANCID for network device configuration management?

Tags: networking, version-control, configuration-management

We've been using Shrubbery Networks RANCID for a good long time to maintain backups of network configurations from many different kinds of devices and have patched and repatched the various perl and expect scripts ad nauseum.

We use Ansible to connect to many of these same devices and we monitor them with SNMP as well, is there a replacement for RANCID that works.  We need something that tracks changes and can be used to restore those changes.  Storing it in git would be ideal, but security is the main focus.

Comment: I'm not sure if someone answers. Do you know https://alternativeto.net/software/rancid/ ?

Comment: A search on github yield these https://github.com/ytti/oxidized , https://github.com/udhos/jazigo